# Argument of type '"68488"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Guid'.ts(2345)

Tags: angular

In using Guid type argument for a database primary key. This is the angular front end interface using Guid type:

```
import { Guid } from 'guid-typescript';

export interface IProduct {
    id: Guid;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    pictureUrl: string;
    productType: string;
    productBrand: string;
  }
```

When attempting to send a Guid type argument in the following function, I get a syntax error, Argument of type '"xxx68488x"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Guid'.ts(2345)

```
  loadProduct(){
   this.shopService.getProduct('dba3ac76-1201-4fe1-8460-8d5de684886c').subscribe
   (response => {this.product = response;
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
}
```

This argument has the red squiggly line under it. How can I pass a Guid argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `Guid.parse` method to convert it from a `string` to `Guid` type:

```
this.shopService.getProduct(Guid.parse('dba3ac76-1201-4fe1-8460-8d5de684886c'))
```